# Does appending to a SQLite table modify the file header?

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, database, sd-card, sqlite

I'm coding a raspbery pi project which gathers data from temperature sensors.
I decided to use SQLite to manage my collected data. I collect the data every 30 seconds and append it to my database.

I am a little worried the SD card might get faulty if I do this long enough.
 I have checked online, and an SD card can withstand around 100k writing cycles, this means around a month of data collection.

Of course, if appending to SQLite table only modifies the filesystem at the added row address, than I'm fine and I can keep collecting data until I run out of space, but If adding a new row also modifies the file header, which by default stays inside the same memory cell on an SD card, then I need to think about a different solution.

So, does appending data to a SQLite table modify the file header?

Comment: What filesystem are you using? (And don't SD cards have internal wear-leveling?)

Comment: @grawity it's ext4